# Accessing "who you are with" and "where you are" tags of a post using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm working with the Facebook API using FQL and I'd like to know how to access the people and location I tagged in the post.

The stream table seems to contain everything apart from these two things. Please help.

EDIT: By tagged people, I mean the option you can add when you select the "who are you with?" option when making a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per http://developers.beta.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/:

The `stream` table has

- **tagged_ids**: An array of IDs tagged in the message of the post.
- **attachment.fb_checkin**: Contains the checkin information

Comment: The tagged_ids field doesn't have the information, I need. It is filled only when I tag something in the body of the message, AFAIK.

By tagged people, I mean the option you can add when you select the "who are you with?" option when making a new post.

I printed the attachment for a test post I'd made, but it just gave me an empty JSON docement. Do I need to access each sub-element individually?

Comment: I tried it again. The tagged_ids field gave me the people I tagged. But the attachment.fb_checkin element is still empty.